# 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte reading a file in Python3.4 but not in Python2.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I was trying to read a file in python2.7, and it was readen perfectly. The problem that I have is when I execute the same program in Python3.4 and then appear the error:

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 424: invalid continuation byte'
```

Also, when I run the program in Windows (with python3.4), the error doesn't appear. The first line of the document is:
    `Codi;Codi_lloc_anonim;Nom`

and the code of my program is:

```
def lectdict(filename,colkey,colvalue):
    f = open(filename,'r')
    D = dict()

    for line in f:
       if line == '\n': continue
       D[line.split(';')[colkey]] = D.get(line.split(';')[colkey],[]) + [line.split(';')[colvalue]]

f.close
return D

Traduccio = lectdict('Noms_departaments_centres.txt',1,2)
```

Comment: What non-ASCII content and encoding does your text file have?

Comment: it seems that python assumes that the file is utf-8 but it;s not actually true, can you try open(filename, 'r', encoding='latin-1') maybe?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Python2,

```
f = open(filename,'r')
for line in f:
```

reads lines from the file *as bytes*.

In Python3, the same code reads lines from the file *as strings*. Python3
strings are what Python2 call `unicode` objects. These are bytes decoded
according to some encoding. The default encoding in Python3 is `utf-8`.

The error message

```
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf2 in position 424: invalid continuation byte'
```

shows Python3 is trying to decode the bytes as `utf-8`. Since there is an error, the file apparently does not contain *`utf-8` encoded bytes*.

To fix the problem you need to **specify the correct encoding** of the file:

```
with open(filename, encoding=enc) as f:
    for line in f:
```

If you do not know the correct encoding, you could run this program to simply
try all the encodings known to Python. If you are lucky there will be an
encoding which turns the bytes into recognizable characters.  Sometimes more
than one encoding may *appear* to work, in which case you'll need to check and
compare the results carefully.

```
# Python3
import pkgutil
import os
import encodings

def all_encodings():
    modnames = set(
        [modname for importer, modname, ispkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(
            path=[os.path.dirname(encodings.__file__)], prefix='')])
    aliases = set(encodings.aliases.aliases.values())
    return modnames.union(aliases)

filename = '/tmp/test'
encodings = all_encodings()
for enc in encodings:
    try:
        with open(filename, encoding=enc) as f:
            # print the encoding and the first 500 characters
            print(enc, f.read(500))
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: Maybe https://cdn.rawgit.com/tripleee/8bit/master/encodings.html#f2 can help you narrow down the search for the correct encoding.  The trial and error approach isn't really viable if you don't know what the bytes are supposed to represent -- a random string in a random 8-bit encoding is a valid but even more random string in most other 8-bit encodings.

Comment: @tripleee since it works in windows i'm almost sure its cp1250 as that would be the default there no?

Comment: For values of "there" where that's the default, well, yes; but not universally.  The default code page depends on how the system was installed in the first place.  But if you know that the source is a regular US or West European install of Windows, I believe [cp1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) would be the expected default.  It differs from [cp1250](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1250) which is for East European languages.

Comment: @user3012759 For example, 0xF2 would be ň in cp1250 but ò in cp1252.

Comment: Im still shaken there are this many character encodings...

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I did the same as @unutbu tell me. The result was a lot of encodings one of these are cp1250, for that reason I change :

```
f = open(filename,'r')
```

to

```
f = open(filename,'r', encoding='cp1250')
```

like @triplee suggest me. And now I can read my files.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I can't change encoding because my file is really UTF-8 encoded. But some rows are corrupted and causes the same error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 7092: invalid continuation byte
```

My decision is to open file in *binary mode*:

```
open(filename, 'rb')
```